# Python-pptx: How to update existing data on second and third slide

Tags: python-pptx

On an existing PowerPoint, I'm updating charts (e.g. line graphs, bar charts) that are on each slide (i.e. slides 1, 2, and 3). I can update the first slide using the code below, but can't access the data for the second slide.

How can I access the chart data on the second slide?

```
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = dates_str

chart_data.add_series('Line 1', line_1_data)
chart_data.add_series('Line 2', line_2_data)
chart_data.add_series('Line 3', line_3_data)

chart.replace_data(chart_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured this one out. The code below needs to be placed before updating any charts/tables on the second slide.

```
# Set slide variable equal to the second slide 
slide = prs.slides[1]

# Reference shape via IDX value
chart = slide.shapes[1].chart

# Set chart_data variable
chart_data = CategoryChartData()
```